# Batch SFTP commands with Python and Paramiko

Tags: python, ssh, sftp, paramiko

I am porting some batch jobs from Window to Linux. These are .bat scripts on Windows and I am rewriting them in Python to run on Linux

On Windows, we currently use putty to SFTP files and run commands like this:

```
psftp user@host -i privatekey.ppk -batch -b script.txt
```

This executes the putty SFTP commands found in **script.txt** in batch. Example below:

```
SCRIPT.TXT example

 cd mydir
 lcd outbox
 get myremotefile.txt mylocalfile.txt
 get myotherremotefile.txt myotherlocalfile.txt
 bye
```

I am trying to find a way to use the same batch script (script.txt) in my python script to minimise the amount of changes overall. I've been looking into [paramiko](https://www.paramiko.org/) but so far I have not been able to find a way to execute the sftp commands in bulk via a script file.

An alternative would be to spawn a sub-process to execute the sftp command with the -b option but would prefer a python native solution if possible.

What do you think? Are there other options out there to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The commands in you script are `psftp` commands. Not *"SFTP commands"* (there are no SFTP commands). In general, no other application nor library understands them. Except for OpenSSH `sftp`, as PuTTY `psftp` was made to be somewhat compatible.

If you want to use a native Python SFTP library, like Paramiko or pysftp, you will need to use its API. And that means rewriting your code. It's not difficult.

Comment: Not really, those are SFTP commands. There is nothing there that won't work with sftp -b. I've just tested it and it has worked. What specific command are you saying does not work?

Comment: OK, PuTTY `psftp` is made to be somewhat compatible with OpenSSH `sftp`. But still, there are no "SFTP commands". There are only commands of respective SFTP clients.

Comment: True, but considering psftp has been implemented to be compatible (or close to) with OpenSSH sftp, I believe I can get the result I want by spawning a subprocess call to an OpenSSH sftp command, like so:
`rc = subprocess.call(f'sftp -b {pathToScript} {args.userAndHost}')`

Comment: Sure, but you have asked for a native Python solution.

Comment: Preferably a native python solution if I could keep the script file somehow and avoid having to change all my scripts. If not possible, spawning a sub-process is acceptable. I appreciate your help.